# X3250 Server: stuck at firmware screen

Tags: linux, php, exchange, sql, xenserver

The server is initialize, then it is stuck at the IBM System X Server Firmware screen (before F1, F12 appears, etc). You can see in the attached image.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=2e573552-118b-4186-b9b8-ba9c971f46c3&ps=25

I load default setting in bios after that it is stuck firmware screen. no error light in hardware indicator.

Thanks,